# Select Distinct Top One Record by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am writing a script to compare software between servers but have a many-to-many relational situation to execute this cleanly. I'm thinking a distinct-top by latest date type of query may help. So that I can go from this

[image]

To this shortened and clean list

[image]

I am not exactly sure how to approach this? Should I start with a sort, then top distinct by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by software_list order by date desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a correlated subquery?

```
select t.*
from t t2
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.software_list = t.software_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using LAST_VALUE.  Works without a subquery

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTEST;
go
select * INTO #tTEST from (values 
('Software1', '1.0.0.1', '1900-01-01'),
('Software1', '1.1.1.1', '2020-03-04'),
('Software2', '3.2.2.1', '1900-01-01'),
('Software2', '3.3.3.1', '2020-03-04'),
('Software2', '4.5.0.0', '2020-05-07')) V(Software_List, [Version], [Date]);
```

Query

```
select distinct Software_List, 
       last_value([Version]) over (partition by Software_List order by [Date]
       rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) [Version],
       last_value([Date]) over (partition by Software_List order by [Date]
       rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) [Date]
from #tTEST t;
```

Results

```
Software_List   Version Date
Software1       1.1.1.1 2020-03-04
Software2       4.5.0.0 2020-05-07
```